# comparison of amplification by CE amplifer and an op-amp

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier

What are the differences in working of a common emitter amplifier and an op-amp? They both contain transistors, so what causes the difference and what are the differences?

Comment: Could you narrow the question down so we can attempt to fit an answer into the space provided? Entire text books have been written on less.

Comment: @NickJohnson had the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The differences are numerous, but I'll attempt to summarise.

An opamp is a differential amplifier. That is, it amplifies the difference between its two inputs. An ideal opamp has the following characteristics of interest:

- Infinite voltage gain
- Infinite input impedance
- Zero output impedance

Real opamps deviate from this, obviously, but generally share the characteristics of having very high input impedance, very low output impedance, and very high gain. Opamps make use of negative feedback to control gain, since their open-loop gain is extremely high.

A common emitter amplifier is a very simple single-transistor amplifier.

- It's single-ended, rather than differential: it amplifies a voltage with reference to ground.
- Its input impedance depends on the emitter resistor and the transistor's gain, and is a lot lower than an opamp's.
- Its output impedance depends on the collector resistor, and is a lot higher than an opamp's.

Those are a few of the differences, but there are many others. For instance, a common emitter amplifier's linearity is worse as you increase the gain, and its quiescent current draw depends on the input and output impedance you want.

tl;dr: An opamp is an attempt to approach the "ideal amplifier" within the constraints of practical electrical engineering. A CE amplifier is a straightforward but limited single transistor voltage amplifier.